# How is the mean for the Cattell IQ tests calculated?

Tags: measurement, intelligence, iq

[British Mensa](https://www.mensa.org.uk/) uses [Cattell Culture Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattell_Culture_Fair_Intelligence_Test) and Cattell III B tests.

- The Cattell Culture Fair Test has a mean and SD of 100 and 16 respectively.
- The Cattell III B has a mean and SD of 100 and 24 respectively.

What sample is used to establish the mean and standard deviation?

**Reference**

1. Cattell RB. Theory of fluid and crystallized intelligence: A critical experiment. J Educ Psychol. 1963;54: 1–22. doi:10.1037/h0046743